# how to delete default style rules in gridview devexpress?

Tags: gridview, devexpress-windows-ui

I have a column in the GridView named UnitPrice (data type: Integer). I dont' choose any Format Rules. when I run the program, then this column is set default Rule (Format Rules): data format using Format Bar. The version of Devexpress is 15.1. How to delete (or dont' display) default rule in gridview control? Thanks!

Comment: Please add your code related to the issue you are having.

Comment: you should add code or explain clearly. You can set something at the begin such as disable row edit, set columns size, disable search panel etc. These are already property and you can find them in Properties view of Visual Studio